CosmosDB NoSQL - Filter two JSON properties for list of IDs formatted as a number and as a string
I'm trying to get the rows whose Fields.FieldId is in a list of numbers (eg: 7942 to 7950) or whose Fields.ParentFieldReference is in the same list of numbers but in a string format (eg: "7942", ..., "7950").
I tried the following but I'm only getting rows that meet the FieldId condition and not the ParentFieldReference condition as well:
SELECT c.ID, f.FieldId, f.FieldValue, f.ParentFieldReference FROM c
JOIN f IN c.Fields
WHERE c.ID = '99999998_1_1_039075'
AND (
    f.FieldId IN (7942, 7943, 7944, 7945, 7946, 7947, 7948, 7949, 7950, 7951, 8305)
    OR ARRAY_CONTAINS(['7942', '7943', '7944', '7945', '7946', '7947', '7948', '7949', '7950', '7951', '8305'], f.ParentFieldReference, true)
)

I have tried using f.ParentFieldReference IN (list) but I'm still getting the same result. Does anyone know where I went wrong here?
Sample data as follows:
{
"ID": "99999998_1_1_039075",
"Fields": [
    {
        "FieldId": 79421,
        "FieldValue": "...",
        "ParentFieldReference": "7942"
    }
]
},
{
"ID": "99999998_1_1_039075",
"Fields": [
    {
        "FieldId": 7943,
        "FieldValue": "...",
        "ParentFieldReference": null
    }
]
}


Try with the below query to get list of numbers between 7942 to 7950 or whose Fields.ParentFieldReference is in the same list of numbers which are in string format ( "7942" to "7950").
Query I tried with:
SELECT c.ID, f.FieldId, f.FieldValue, f.ParentFieldReference 
FROM c
JOIN f IN c.Fields
WHERE c.ID = '99999998_1_1_039075'
AND (
    (f.FieldId >= 7942 AND f.FieldId <= 7950)
    AND (f.ParentFieldReference IN ('7942', '7943', '7944', '7945', '7946', '7947', '7948', '7949', '7950'))
)

Output:
[
    {
        "ID": "99999998_1_1_039075",
        "FieldId": 7950,
        "FieldValue": "Value C",
        "ParentFieldReference": "7943"
    },
    {
        "ID": "99999998_1_1_039075",
        "FieldId": 7944,
        "FieldValue": "Value F",
        "ParentFieldReference": "7942"
    },
    {
        "ID": "99999998_1_1_039075",
        "FieldId": 7946,
        "FieldValue": "Value H",
        "ParentFieldReference": "7950"
    },
    {
        "ID": "99999998_1_1_039075",
        "FieldId": 7949,
        "FieldValue": "Value K",
        "ParentFieldReference": "7944"
    }
]


Could you try with the above code once and let me know if any errors you are facing with?
